# IPC Using Protobuf and Memory Mapped Files C#

Tags: c#, stream, ipc, protobuf-net, memory-mapped-files

I'm writing a project to pass an object from a parent application to a child application. I'm using Protobuf to serialize and deserialize the data. I'm also using a Non-Persisted Memory-Mapped File to write to when serializing (and read from when deserializing). Here is the code:

```
[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
public class Test
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int ID { get; private set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public bool TestBool { get; private set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string MessageBody { get; private set; }

    public Test(int id, bool testBool, string messageBody)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.TestBool = testBool;
        this.MessageBody = messageBody;
    }


    public void Serialize()
    {
        MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("testmap", 1000);
        using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        {
            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, this, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }

    public static Test Deserialize()
    {
        using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("testmap"))
        {
            using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
            {
                return Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Test>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            }
        }
    }
}

//On the parent application
var msg = new SharedLibrary.Test(1234, true, "Test message hahah");
msg.Serialize();
//spawn child application



//On the child application
Test result = Test.Deserialize();
```

When I run this code I get the following error (when Serializer.Deserialize is called):

<s>Exception thrown: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in protobuf-net.dll
Additional information: Invalid field in source data: 0
I think this error is occurring because The stream is larger than the actual data it contains. When the stream is deserialized I think it starts reading beyond the actual data.</s>

Exception thrown: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in protobuf-net.dll
Additional information: No parameterless constructor found for Test

I'm not sure the best way to fix this however. Is there a way to read the bytes from a stream until the is no data left and then stop? If not can I solve this another way?

Comment: A wild guess, It might be because the properties `set` are private? The use of `Attributes` might indicate that reflection is used.

Comment: I tried that out just to be safe, but the same error is thrown. I'm pretty sure Protobuf just calls the constructor so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Actually I just discovered something. I also had a default constructor public Test() { }. When I removed that, a new exception is thrown: Exception thrown: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in protobuf-net.dll
Additional information: No parameterless constructor found for Test ... So it appears that the stream that Deserialize is receiving is empty? Not sure why that would be occuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure the best way to fix this

1. add a parameterless constructor (it can be `private` if you like), or
2. add the `SkipConstructor = true` as parameters on the `[ProtoContract(...)]` on your type

> however. Is there a way to read the bytes from a stream until the is no data left and then stop?

Yes, that is the default in protocol buffers, since the outermost message does not include a length marker or end marker (it is designed to be appendable). However, *in your case*, this is probably *not* what you want, as there will be various garbage (possibly all zeros, possibly not) *after* the data you serialize. You might want to use `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` instead. And if your data is only 1000 bytes, `MemoryStream` will be fine - no need to use unmanaged memory.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect your changes. That last part about the unmanaged memory.. Are you saying that in my case I should just use a MemoryStream instead of a MemoryMappedFile?

Comment: @user2481095 I don't know enough about your specific use case to say that with certainty, however, I wouldn't *leap* to using unmanaged memory. If there is a good reason: great